# Get bound object value of angular component from its controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-components

I have an angular component:

```
module.exports = {
    bindings: {
        vulnerability: '<',
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
       //want to get value of vulnerability from above
       $scope.vulnerability  // doesn't work
    }],
};
```

which i reference in an ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="vulnerability in vulnerabilities" class="vulnerability-item">
   <vulnerability-item  vulnerability="vulnerability"> </vulnerability-item>
</div>
```

The value of vulnerability isn't going to change once the directive is called so I don't need to watch that value, just to reference it once it gets set.

I did put a `$scope.$watch` on the property just to see if it worked and it did trigger but I couldn't see the new or old value in the handler of the watch so it didn't help me anyway.

I tried `$scope.vulnerability` and `$ctrl.vulnerability` which is how I'd reference that property in the directives template but neither worked. How do I get the bound value that is passed in?

adding this watch:

```
    $scope.$watch('vulnerability', function (oldV, newV) {
        console.log('old', oldV)
        console.log('new', newV)
    })
```

I get a `new undefined` and `old undefined` in the console for each  instance of the component although if i change `$scope.$watch('vulnerability'` to `$scope.$watch('nonsense')` It still fires the logs once for each component.

Comment: Please, update the question with your attempt on using `$scope.$watch`. For 1.5 and components [`$onChanges`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) hook is preferable.

Comment: As I mentioned I have no interest in watching the value for changes. Is there no way to just obtain that value directly from the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value isn't supposed to be changed, it should be bound once, `vulnerability="::vulnerability"`. This gives the context to the question (and also saves some time on optimization).

In this case `$onInit` hook may be used:

```
...
controller: function() {
   this.$onInit = function () {
     this.vulnerability
   }
},
```

Comment: turned out to be that it needed to be referenced on `this` not `$scope` as in `this.vulnerability` within the controller

Could you change your answer to that and elaborate more on `vulnerability="::vulnerability"` and ill accept it

Comment: Ok. As for one-time bindings, see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding . It is a good practice to use them wherever possible, it gives a proper context to the code and does a good job on initial optimization.